# Custom scrollbar not scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'v having great difficulties copying someone else [work](https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar) on github.com

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to build(copy) custom scrollbars for my website.

**What is not working**

Ok, so I downloaded the folder right, I create an index.html and link all the files to it. So when I run that index.html on a browser(chrome, or firefox) the bar does not slide up and down, it is in a still position; But the content still scrolls.
Also I can't grab at the bar with cursor to scroll the text. Im  on a surface pro 4, 128gb  $800 value but got it for $200, so I was only able to scroll using the touchscreen.

**What I want**

I just want custom bar like the one in the link, but have it actually work well.
If you have a better solution then the one they are showing please let me know!

[Here is there example!](http://buzinas.github.io/simple-scrollbar/)

[Here is my example!](https://instagram.com/p/BkHZ5ZAFShJ/)

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SimpleScrollbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="simple-scrollbar.css">
    <!--[if IE 9]><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/classlist/2014.01.31/classList.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="simple-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <a href="https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar"><img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/365986a132ccd6a44c23a9169022c0b5c890c387/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6769746875622f726962626f6e732f666f726b6d655f72696768745f7265645f6161303030302e706e67" alt="Fork me on GitHub" data-canonical-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_red_aa0000.png"></a>
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 200px; display: inline-block;" ss-container="" class="ss-container"><div class="ss-wrapper"><div class="ss-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div></div><div class="ss-scroll" style="height: 65.6455%; top: 0%; right: -191px;"></div></div>
    <section style="height: 300px; width: 500px; display: inline-block;" ss-container="" class="ss-container"><div class="ss-wrapper"><div class="ss-content">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
      <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?</p>
    </div></div><div class="ss-scroll" style="height: 51.3699%; top: 0%; right: -491px;"></div></section>


</body></html>
```

**CSS**

```
.ss-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}

.ss-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 18px);
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ss-content.rtl {
  width: calc(100% + 18px);
  right: auto;
}

.ss-scroll {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 9px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
}

.ss-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.ss-container:hover .ss-scroll,
.ss-container:active .ss-scroll {
  opacity: 1;
}

**.ss-grabbed {
  -o-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

**Js-1; simple-scrollbar.min.js**

```
    ! function(t, e) {
    "object" == typeof exports ? module.exports = e(window, document) : t.SimpleScrollbar = e(window, document)
}(this, function(t, e) {
    function s(t) {
        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t, "data-simple-scrollbar") || Object.defineProperty(t, "data-simple-scrollbar", {
            value: new o(t)
        })
    }

    function i(t, s) {
        function i(t) {
            var e = t.pageY - a;
            a = t.pageY, n(function() {
                s.el.scrollTop += e / s.scrollRatio
            })
        }

        function r() {
            t.classList.remove("ss-grabbed"), e.body.classList.remove("ss-grabbed"), e.removeEventListener("mousemove", i), e.removeEventListener("mouseup", r)
        }
        var a;
        t.addEventListener("mousedown", function(s) {
            return a = s.pageY, t.classList.add("ss-grabbed"), e.body.classList.add("ss-grabbed"), e.addEventListener("mousemove", i), e.addEventListener("mouseup", r), !1
        })
    }

    function r(t) {
        for (this.target = t, this.direction = window.getComputedStyle(this.target).direction, this.bar = '<div class="ss-scroll">', this.wrapper = e.createElement("div"), this.wrapper.setAttribute("class", "ss-wrapper"), this.el = e.createElement("div"), this.el.setAttribute("class", "ss-content"), "rtl" === this.direction && this.el.classList.add("rtl"), this.wrapper.appendChild(this.el); this.target.firstChild;) this.el.appendChild(this.target.firstChild);
        this.target.appendChild(this.wrapper), this.target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", this.bar), this.bar = this.target.lastChild, i(this.bar, this), this.moveBar(), this.el.addEventListener("scroll", this.moveBar.bind(this)), this.el.addEventListener("mouseenter", this.moveBar.bind(this)), this.target.classList.add("ss-container");
        var s = window.getComputedStyle(t);
        "0px" === s.height && "0px" !== s["max-height"] && (t.style.height = s["max-height"])
    }

    function a() {
        for (var t = e.querySelectorAll("*[ss-container]"), i = 0; i < t.length; i++) s(t[i])
    }
    var n = t.requestAnimationFrame || t.setImmediate || function(t) {
        return setTimeout(t, 0)
    };
    r.prototype = {
        moveBar: function(t) {
            var e = this.el.scrollHeight,
                s = this.el.clientHeight,
                i = this;
            this.scrollRatio = s / e;
            var r = "rtl" === i.direction,
                a = r ? i.target.clientWidth - i.bar.clientWidth + 18 : -1 * (i.target.clientWidth - i.bar.clientWidth);
            n(function() {
                i.scrollRatio >= 1 ? i.bar.classList.add("ss-hidden") : (i.bar.classList.remove("ss-hidden"), i.bar.style.cssText = "height:" + Math.max(100 * i.scrollRatio, 10) + "%; top:" + i.el.scrollTop / e * 100 + "%;right:" + a + "px;")
            })
        }
    }, e.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", a), r.initEl = s, r.initAll = a;
    var o = r;
    return o
});
```

**js-2; simple-scrollbar.js**

```
;(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory(window, document)
  } else {
    root.SimpleScrollbar = factory(window, document)
  }
})(this, function(w, d) {
  var raf = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.setImmediate || function(c) { return setTimeout(c, 0); };

  function initEl(el) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(el, 'data-simple-scrollbar')) return;
    Object.defineProperty(el, 'data-simple-scrollbar', { value: new SimpleScrollbar(el) });
  }

  // Mouse drag handler
  function dragDealer(el, context) {
    var lastPageY;

    el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      lastPageY = e.pageY;
      el.classList.add('ss-grabbed');
      d.body.classList.add('ss-grabbed');

      d.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
      d.addEventListener('mouseup', stop);

      return false;
    });

    function drag(e) {
      var delta = e.pageY - lastPageY;
      lastPageY = e.pageY;

      raf(function() {
        context.el.scrollTop += delta / context.scrollRatio;
      });
    }

    function stop() {
      el.classList.remove('ss-grabbed');
      d.body.classList.remove('ss-grabbed');
      d.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
      d.removeEventListener('mouseup', stop);
    }
  }

  // Constructor
  function ss(el) {
    this.target = el;

    this.direction = w.getComputedStyle(this.target).direction;

    this.bar = '<div class="ss-scroll">';

    this.wrapper = d.createElement('div');
    this.wrapper.setAttribute('class', 'ss-wrapper');

    this.el = d.createElement('div');
    this.el.setAttribute('class', 'ss-content');

    if (this.direction === 'rtl') {
      this.el.classList.add('rtl');
    }

    this.wrapper.appendChild(this.el);

    while (this.target.firstChild) {
      this.el.appendChild(this.target.firstChild);
    }
    this.target.appendChild(this.wrapper);

    this.target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.bar);
    this.bar = this.target.lastChild;

    dragDealer(this.bar, this);
    this.moveBar();

    w.addEventListener('resize', this.moveBar.bind(this));
    this.el.addEventListener('scroll', this.moveBar.bind(this));
    this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.moveBar.bind(this));

    this.target.classList.add('ss-container');

    var css = w.getComputedStyle(el);
    if (css['height'] === '0px' && css['max-height'] !== '0px') {
        el.style.height = css['max-height'];
    }
  }

  ss.prototype = {
    moveBar: function(e) {
      var totalHeight = this.el.scrollHeight,
          ownHeight = this.el.clientHeight,
          _this = this;

      this.scrollRatio = ownHeight / totalHeight;

      var isRtl = _this.direction === 'rtl';
      var right = isRtl ?
        (_this.target.clientWidth - _this.bar.clientWidth + 18) :
        (_this.target.clientWidth - _this.bar.clientWidth) * -1;

      raf(function() {
        // Hide scrollbar if no scrolling is possible
        if(_this.scrollRatio >= 1) {
          _this.bar.classList.add('ss-hidden')
        } else {
          _this.bar.classList.remove('ss-hidden')
          _this.bar.style.cssText = 'height:' + Math.max(_this.scrollRatio * 100, 10) + '%; top:' + (_this.el.scrollTop / totalHeight ) * 100 + '%;right:' + right + 'px;';
        }
      });
    }
  }

  function initAll() {
    var nodes = d.querySelectorAll('*[ss-container]');

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      initEl(nodes[i]);
    }
  }

  d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initAll);
  ss.initEl = initEl;
  ss.initAll = initAll;

  var SimpleScrollbar = ss;
  return SimpleScrollbar;
});
```

**Side notes**

If anyone has a better solution please let me know.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you did was only copying the whole HTML output of the related site.

If you would like to use the given library, you have to do what they say in the README section:

https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar#manual-binding

To use it like this way you need to add the scripts to your code base. That's where the question about the two javascript file comes up:
There are two given javascript file, one, that ends WITH `.min.js` and one WITHOUT `.min.js.`. The min refers to `minified`, so that it doesn't take up as much space.

And please, don't share videos on Instagram. Very unprofessional.

Comment: Ok cool, well sorry first time using GitHub. Why it's it unprofessional to use Instagram?  I mean tons of professionals do it? I kinda see what your talking about. But Instagram is quick and easy. Anyway thank you

Comment: I still don't get it because it's JavaScript, I'm new to it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with the basics in this case and copy code later for your own website.

Great tutorial, nice examples can be found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jS/default.asp